# In IOS is it possible for users of the app to be able to select in a table view which tab bar items they want

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

I am creating an app for people to be able to view ad get notifications from quotes the like. The quotes are separated into categories and the user can pick which categories of quotes they want to see. The changes they make will affect the bar button items. In Swift please

Comment: Please show what you have done so far to try to do this and why it isn't working. If you don't know how to do it at all then developer.apple.com is your friend.

Comment: I simply have tried and failed I don't even know if it's possible

Comment: Well, to answer the "is it possible" question, your description of what you want is pretty vague, but I still feel pretty confident in saying that yes, it is possible. But obviously, no one is going to do it for you. It sounds like you do not know very much at all about iOS development so that is the first thing you need to correct. Which is why developer.apple.com is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

after reading your question, about the idea you have, I can tell you that it is very much possible. It's not to hard to do as long as you take your time and think about it. I won't give you any of the code and you don't seem to know what you are doing that well.

Don't worry though I am 100% sure that if you do some research about (Hint hint) the two parts that you want to come together I'm sure you will find the answer.

YES it is very do able!

Also don't ask for the code no one will give it to you! Try breaking it down and figuring it out yourself

Good luck have a good day!